# IonSearchbar getInputEtlement how to set attribute disabled?

Tags: ionic3, ionic4

I am working in ionic v4 and 
I have 2 `ion-searchbars` when clicked on the second one I want to disable the first search-bar.

I have red in the docs that you could get the native element with the following code:

```
@ViewChild('searchbar') searchbar: IonSearchbar;

ngOnInit() {
    const elem = this.searchbar.getInputElement;
    console.log(elem);
    // google.maps.places.Autocomplete(elem);
}
```

But how to I disable that native input element?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-searchbar #searchbar1 (ionFocus)="ionFocus()"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-searchbar #searchbar2 ></ion-searchbar>
```

```
  @ViewChild('searchbar1') searchbar1: IonSearchbar;

  @ViewChild('searchbar2') searchbar2: IonSearchbar;


  ionFocus(): void {
    this.searchbar2.getInputElement().then( data => {
      data.disabled = true
      console.log(data.disabled = true);
    });
  }
```